# JSF Exception - 404 500 codes

Tags: exception, jsf-2, http-status-code-404

I have a JSF2 application which uses primefaces 3.0.

When I include 404 error code or 500 error code in my web.xml

```
 <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/faces/404.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
```

I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doLastPhaseActions(ELFlash.java:607)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.responseFlushBuffer(ExternalContextImpl.java:857)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
```

How to suppress this exception? Am I missing something on my exception handling?

Here is the 404.xhmtl. I am not using any reference bean in 404 xhtml.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      id="htmlPage">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body id="body">
        <center>
            <div class="headerTop">
                <table id="pageHeader">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            Header
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table id="pageContent" style="background-color: white;min-width: 60%;max-width: 90%" >
                <tr>
                    <td  align="center" valign="top" style="min-height: 600px;">
                        <table width="100%" style="float: left">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    404 Error
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table style=" width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div>
                            footer
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are accessing any backing bean in 404.xhtml, please post the code for them as well.

Comment: I have posted my 404.xhtml. I am not accessing any backing bean if you see.

Comment: Same here, this is really a bug.

Comment: If you have an unexpected error, which obviusly could be anything, you should redirect to a simple static page, not an xhtml, or maybe a jsp, but not to a JSF (xhtml) page, do it and it will work fine.